# js peerConnection doesn't connect if using mobile internet

Tags: javascript, mobile, mediastream, peer-connection

**Description:**

I'm using peerConnection between two computers and send mediaStream from canvas to the video-element of other computer

**Problem:**

If I'm using mobile internet on computer that connect's to host computer then connection `readyState` standing still in `connecting`
Ice candidates received correctly and `remote` and `local` descriptions was sended successfuly too. But channel wasn't opened

**Question:**

So I don't have any idea why does it happend?

Comment: check the `console.log` what the error showing on that?

Comment: nothing, I did it already

Comment: are you using STUN/TURN?